# xcode - autoresize not working

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, autoresize

I have an app with a tabbar and navigation controllers added to it.

The views are made with XIBs. 
I set the simulated metrics to iPad size (768 width - setting is «Freeform») and use regular autoresizing for width and height, so the view should adjust to the device-size.
(I don't use the auto-layout!).

Now, when I start the app, the views aren't scaled to the device-width. No matter which device I choose, the views don't resize. They're always 768px wide.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

[edit]

Here are some screenshots of my settings...

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post a scrren shot how it is coming in simulator and how you want?

Comment: you try to set the view in full width for all devices

Comment: @siba: well - it just uses the full width (768px) and thus, on an iPhone it crops the screen...

Answer (score 2):

do use autolayout is the simplest answer I can give you :) What you see in the XIB is just a meta representation of a view component, does not mean it will render exactly as you see in the editor. So you should always work with autolayouts to avoid such situiation.

Comment: I'm not very fond of auto layout but it might be the only solution.